# Merge Statement VS Lookup Transformation

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis

I am stuck with a problem with different views.

Present Scenario:

I am using SSIS packages to get data from Server A to Server B every 15 minutes.Created 10 packages for 10 different tables and also created 10 staging table for the same. In the DataFlow Task it is selecting data from server A with ID greater last imported ID and dumping them onto a Staging table.(Each table has its own stagin table).After the DataFlow task I am using a MERGE statement to merge records from Staging table to Destination table where ID is NO Matched.

Problem:

This will take care all new records inserted but if once a record is picked by SSIS job and is update at the source I am not able to pick it up again and not able to grab the updated data.

Questions:

- How will I be able to achieve the Update with impacting the source database server too much.
- Do I use MERGE statement and select 10,000 records every single run?(every 15 minutes)
- Do I use LookUp transformation to do the updates
- Some tables have more than 2 million records and growing, so what is the best approach for them.

## NOTE:

I can truncate tables in destination and reinsert complete data for the first run.

Edit:

The Source has a column 'LAST_UPDATE_DATE' which I can Use in my query.

Comment: Are you saying existing records get updated in the source and you need to identify them? You need to add something at the source like a 'last updated' column or triggers/log tables to capture CDC info.

Comment: I would implement in the source and in the staging and final table as well these 4 columns: - CreateBy, CreatedOn, ModifyBy, ModifyOn. I also define the natural or business key of the tables, in this way you can avoid the usage of this story about the ID greater than something that I'm not able to understand. If you provide this info and maybe a diagram I will be able to help you

Comment: @ElectricLlama: Yes , the existing records get updated.Using a trigger is not encouraged.

Comment: So the problem is you don't know which records in the source have been updated. You either need an existing last updated column (which would need to be populated by the app which alters the data), or a trigger to capture and identify changes at the database level. That's all there is to it.

Comment: You definitely need to clarify: can you currently identify changed records in the source? (by CDC, a last_updated field or something like that)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your statements correctly it sounds like you're pretty close to your solution. If you currently have a merge statement that includes the insert (where source does not match destination) you should be able to easily include the update statement for the (where source matches destination).

example:

```
MERGE target_table as destination_table_alias
USING ( 
SELECT <column_name(s)>
 FROM  source_table
) AS source_alias
ON 
 [source_table].[table_identifier] = [destination_table_alias].[table_identifier]

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET [destination_table_alias.column_name1] = mySource.column_name1,
    [destination_table_alias.column_name2] = mySource.column_name2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT 
([column_name1],[column_name2])
VALUES([source_alias].[column_name1],mySource.[column_name2])
```

So, to your points:

1. Update can be achieved via the 'WHEN MATCHED' logic within the merge statement
2. If you have the last ID of the table that you're loading, you can include this as a filter on your select statement so that the dataset is incremental.
3. No lookup is needed with the 'WHEN MATCHED' is utilized.
4. utilizing a select filter in the select portion of the merge statement.

Hope this helps

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP cannot identify which records in the source have been updated, so he cannot stage them. Therefore at this stage nothing in the staging table will ever be NOT MATCHED

Comment: @SWilliams: I write this MERGE statement in a Execute SQL task which will connect only to one data Source(One Server), which means I need to have both source and destination table on the same server. How can i compare tables on two different servers.

Comment: @SWilliams: I have a staging table for this and can populate that, but how much data should I populate? (Top 10000,top2000)Cannot do the complete table as it runs every 15 minutes and have millions of records for few tables.

Comment: snp.it, Is @ElectricLlama correct? You can't identify what's changed in the source system? I'm not sure I understand how you're using a merge statement to pull data from the source if you're loading it into a staging table. There may be a couple of options. 1. Is using Change Data Capture an option? It requires SQL Server Enterprise Edition. If not, 2. Is there a unique key on the source system? If so, you could create a staging table that holds the last loaded ID from the source, and only pull data from the source system that is greater than the last ID loaded. More info is needed.